# HDMI and DVI connected monitors not in dual view on Windows 7 (Intel onboard Gigabyte)

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, intel-graphics

I have a HDMI to DVI cable which is connected to one monitor (HDMI is on PC side) and DVI-DVI connected to other monitor. This seems to work up until the system is fully loaded (the startup logo animation is shown on two screens). When and after I log in only one monitor is active (HDMI-DVI). I'm also unable to detect the other monitor (DVI-DVI).

Any ideas what might be wrong with the setup? Also when I uninstall the Intel Graphics driver both screens are on, but only duplication works.

GA-Z68A-D3H-B3, Intel Z68 Chipset, with fresh VGA driver (15.26.1.64.2618).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly this setup is simply not supported with this hardware. Dual view works fine for: HDMI + DSUB, DVI + DSUB, but not for HDMI + DVI.